# How to delete the Multiuser mode in my mobile?

Tags: adb, root-access, bootloader, delete, realme

I would like to remove(delete) the Multiuser mode in Realme XT.
I want my phone to be simple.

I have unlocked bootloader and rooted my phone and removed all useless bloatwares.

Can someone please give me an adb command or the file in root to delete, So There is no option for Multiuser mode in my mobile.

Comment: Check to maximum number of users with `pm get-max-users`. then set the number of users with `setprop fw.max_users x` where x is the number of users. Use `su` in case you don't have permission.

Comment: The "Multiuser mode" is part of your OS and can not be removed, just disabled. You can delete additional user profiles you have created but messing around with system components will only end up in a non-bootable or bricked phone.